# Using an array of Strings to set section names using titleForHeaderInSection in Swift

Tags: swift

So my goal is as the title states, is to use an array of strings to set the titles for sections I am currently using a switch statement

```
switch section
{
        case 0:
            return "Home"
        case 1:
            return "Work "
        case 2:
            return "Weekend "
        case 4:
            return "Uncatagorized"
        default:
            return ""
}
```

the reason I would like to use an array is because I would like to add to the array from the front in to create a new section. Any suggestions or ideas of a better way.

Comment: What exactly are you having an issue with? Do you know how to create an array of strings in Swift? Do you know how to access an element of an array in Swift? Simply use the table view section as the index into the string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `section` parameter to subscript an array stored as a static class constant array of your choosing.

```
class YourTableViewDataSource {
    static let SectionTitles = [
        "Home",
        "Work",
        "Weekend",
        "Uncatagorized"
    ]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        guard SectionTitles.indices ~= section else {
            print("No section title for this section")
            return nil
        }

        return SectionTitles[section]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much new to swift and still shaky with arrays.

Comment: I would suggest you read through the language guide, practice some example problems and follow some tutorials. They're pretty fundamental, writing a program in Swift without them is like writing a novel without an alphabet.